# How to install a Blender Plugin?

Tags: add-on

Trying to install the CATS plugin (https://github.com/GiveMeAllYourCats/cats-blender-plugin)
I extracted it and it was a bunch of confusing files, no .exe files in sight. I downloaded this as a zip. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to unzip the archive. Go to Edit > Blender Preferences, then choose Add-ons section from the sections on the left side and press "Install an add-on" button on top, browse for your zip file, choose the file and press "Install Add-on" button on the bottom next to Cancel button, after add-on is installed you need to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit->Preferences.  Select Add-ons.  Top right of the preferences window press "Install" and navigate to and select the zip file.  This will install it but you have to select the tick box on the left of new installed entry to enable it.

[image: installing add-on]